# Invisible/hidden canvas does not show up in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas

A canvas styled with `visibility: hidden;` is supposed to appear window-sized after one second with this code, right?

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
// draw on canvas.getContext("2d") ...
window.setTimeout(function() {
  canvas.style.visibility = "visible";
}, 1000);
```

It works with IE11, but not with Chrome32 (running on Windows7).
*(Phew, I never though I would find something that works with IE but not with Chrome!)*

I tried using `display: none;` and `canvas.style.display= "block";` to hide and show the canvas and got the same behavior.

Here is a test: http://jsfiddle.net/CX49R/

Oddly, in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CX49R/) with Chrome, the canvas (and its drawn content) appears after you move the mouse over the document area (after the function triggered by `setTimeout` is called, of course). But it never appears if the same HTML+CSS+JS code runs in a single Chrome tab/window (unless you open "Development tools" through "Inspect element", or click on the document area).

What am I missing here? I tried to reduce the code to the minimum of my original scenario.

Comment: on mac, in chrome it works fine. Maybe try z-index: -1 then change it to 0 after a second

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong, it's definitely Chrome acting up. Using display instead of visibility did solve it for me though [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CX49R/1/).

Comment: @Strille, it did not work for me outside of jsfiddle, and without using jQuery. It works with jQuery on Windows7, but not on Chrome running in my Nexus 4/Android 4.4.2

Comment: @Huangism, just tried with `z-index` too. Same thing, nothing happens. It seems something is preventing Chrome from refreshing the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like it's somehow related to the canvas element. Creating a hidden parent div and showing that instead of the canvas element seems to solve the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/CX49R/2/

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <canvas id="myCanvas">Your browser does not support canvas.</canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: It works even in Chrome running in Nexus 4/Android 4.4.2. And not even jQuery (yes, _THE_ jQuery) could make my original solution work there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I'll give you an answer instead.  The issue is not the setTimeout, the issue is with `canvas.style.visibility = "visible";`.  I set up an alert in your timeout and it fired after a second, no problem.  My only guess is that `canvas.style.visibility` is waiting on a mouse event to trigger itself.

Comment: Yeah, looks like that's the issue! So we found a bug?!  :-)

Comment: check the docs for an issue library.  It might be an 'intended' bug, where the action itself is intended so it just won't work in this way.  Strille has a workaround.